# GCP VM Redirect all the request to another URL

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform

We have internal load balancer, where the request is coming to a instance group which is basically the sets of VM.

`Load Balancer -> Instance Group (our service is running on the Port 8080)`

Since we need to redirect one of the request to some other domain, this is done in order to test our new service

```
Load Balancer -> Send Request to VM 1 at port 8080 -> Redirect it newservice.com/filter=<with arguments>

              -> VM 2 and VM 3 service is running on port 8080
```

What's the correct way to do that ? Since new service is not in the same gcp project, any help how we should achieve it ?

I have simple nginx configuration :

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name MY-MACHINE-IP (VM 1)
 return      301 https://newService.com$request_uri;;
}
```

But no redirection is happening

Comment: Are you saying that the VM 2 and VM 3, the VM of the new service are in another project (let's say, project B)? Only the load balancer and the redirection VM are in the project A?

Comment: Please describe which VM's are in which projects (A,B,C), how everything's set up now and how you want it to work when testing new service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 3 ways to make cross-project connections possible: Shared VPC, Cloud VPN or VPC Peering. You may choose the option that most suits your use-case. I would try VPC Peering first.

[Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc)

[Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview)

[VPC Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering)